# Reading stock levels from an array and saving newly adjusted stock levels

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

I'm designing a point-of-sale application that reads stock levels from an array and accepts a booking if there is adequate stock levels.

The new stock levels should then be saved when the exit button on the application is pressed.

Here's my code for the arrays, I have a temp stock array so that if an order is canceled the stock can revert back to its original value.

```
readonly static int[,] Stock = 
    { 
        {23,4,6,8,12,12,8,4,0,3,6,9 },
        {3,4,5,6,45,8,5,2,7,8,9,10 },
        {32,7,10,13,34,19,12,5,4,6,8,10 },
        {12,13,11,12,23,12,4,7,10,8,6,4 },
        {6,2,4,2,4,6,3,4,5,6,7,8 }
    };

//Create an Array for temporary Stock
readonly static int[,] TempStock = 
    { 
        {23,4,6,8,12,12,8,4,0,3,6,9 },
        {3,4,5,6,45,8,5,2,7,8,9,10 },
        {32,7,10,13,34,19,12,5,4,6,8,10 },
        {12,13,11,12,23,12,4,7,10,8,6,4 },
        {6,2,4,2,4,6,3,4,5,6,7,8 }
    };
```

The stock levels are also in an excel file. Would it be easier to read the stock levels from that rather than the array?

Comment: You mean you have those stock values hard-coded? But aren't they dynamic values, that change all the time? If so, you can't have them hard-coded in an array like this. If the values change you have to recompile the application?

Comment: Yes. Store the stock values outside the application so if the application crashes you don't lose your current stock values. Don't store them outside in an excel spreadsheet. There are a 1000000000 better places to store this information where both your application AND excel can see the current stock. Consider using a database here. A simple table called `stock` with columns `product_id` and `current_stock` would be an improvement in your current single-dimension array where you are (I'm guessing) relying on the array index to determine which product is which.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm just looking for some code that would display an error message if an order is made where the quantity of the order > Stock for that product. And that also changes the value of the stock if a legitimate order is put through.